# Limit of $(-1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I appreciate if I could get help to answer this question; what is the limit of $(-1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity? I know that $e^x$ is the answer if the first term under the bracket is 1 not -1.

Comment: See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+to+infinity+(-1%2Bx%2Fn)%5En

Comment: You just take out the factor $(-1)^{n} $ and then you can see that the sequence oscillates between $e^{-x} $ and $-e^{x} $ and hence the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Note:
$$\left(-1+\frac x n\right)^n=(-1)^n\left(1-\frac x n\right)^n$$ now compare $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. And conclude.

Comment: it should be $lim(-1)^n$$e^-x$. But what is the value of $lim(-1)^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be that. It should be that you check at least two cases: subsequences of even and then of odd indexes

Comment: Yes!! Can you check that ? @Isaacadel

Comment: No, i don`t get it. For subsequence with even n, $(-1)^n$ is 1 and it becomes -1 for odd n. So what does that tell me about the value of the limit?

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the even subsequence and $b_n$ the odd subsequence. So you know $a_n\to e^{-x}$ and $b_n\to -e^{-x}$. You have found two subsequences with different limits, so the original sequence have no limit.